# How can I access dictionaries values in python if I have a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have this structure for a dictionary and I need to iterate over it to find if under the key 'items' and right after under the key field there is the value 'status' and the value 'In Progress' under the key 'toString'.

Also, I need to get the date it happened. This can be found one level higher looking for the value under the key 'created'.

I'd tried so many ways and nothing worked. I appreciate your help.

```
{'startAt': 0,
 'maxResults': 18,
 'total': 18,
 'histories': [{'id': '126221979',
   'author': {'self': '<some_URL>',
    'name': '<ID in the system>',
    'key': '<ID in the system>',
    'emailAddress': 'e-mail address',
    'avatarUrls': {'48x48': '<some_URL>',
     '24x24': '<some_URL>',
     '16x16': '<some_URL>',
     '32x32': '<some_URL>'},
    'displayName': 'Display Name',
    'active': True,
    'timeZone': 'America/Sao_Paulo'},
   'created': '2022-02-11T19:22:40.000+0000',
   'items': [{'field': 'Link',
     'fieldtype': 'jira',
     'from': None,
     'fromString': None,
     'to': '<Isue ID>',
     'toString': 'This issue child-of <Some ID>'}]},
  {'id': '126221981',
   'author': {'self': '<some_URL>',
    'name': '<ID in the system>',
    'key': '<ID in the system>',
    'emailAddress': 'e-mail address',
    'avatarUrls': {'48x48': '<some_URL>',
     '24x24': '<some_URL>',
     '16x16': '<some_URL>',
     '32x32': '<some_URL>'},
    'displayName': 'Display Name',
    'active': True,
    'timeZone': 'America/Sao_Paulo'},
   'created': '2022-02-11T19:23:56.000+0000',
   'items': [{'field': 'status',
     'fieldtype': 'jira',
     'from': 1,
     'fromString': 'Open',
     'to': 3,
     'toString': 'In Progress'}
     ]
     },
      {'id': '126221981',
   'author': {'self': '<some_URL>',
    'name': '<ID in the system>',
    'key': '<ID in the system>',
    'emailAddress': 'e-mail address',
    'avatarUrls': {'48x48': '<some_URL>',
     '24x24': '<some_URL>',
     '16x16': '<some_URL>',
     '32x32': '<some_URL>'},
    'displayName': 'Display Name',
    'active': True,
    'timeZone': 'America/Sao_Paulo'},
   'created': '2022-02-11T19:23:56.000+0000',
   'items': [{'field': 'status',
     'fieldtype': 'jira',
     'from': 1,
     'fromString': 'Open',
     'to': 3,
     'toString': 'In Progress'}
     ]
     }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please post what you tried, and what issue(s) you had with it.

Comment: The last try was this one: 

dict_.get('startAt', {}).get('id', {}).get('items', [])

I got the error

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: You read the value of the key 'startAt'. This value is an integer with the value `0`. Now you try to do `0.get('id', {}).get('items', [])` Can you see why this won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd_json_normalize`:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(d['histories'], 'items', 'created')
    field fieldtype  from fromString         to                       toString                       created
0    Link      jira   NaN       None  <Isue ID>  This issue child-of <Some ID>  2022-02-11T19:22:40.000+0000
1  status      jira   1.0       Open          3                    In Progress  2022-02-11T19:23:56.000+0000
2  status      jira   1.0       Open          3                    In Progress  2022-02-11T19:23:56.000+0000
```